# Link back to previous page while link's text changes using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Please take a look at my code here on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-level-deep-route?file=src/App.js).

Now this is what I want:

1. I want the **Home** link on the Navbar to be a link to the previous page. (e.g. In the `Level1` page, the **Home** link should take me back to `Category1` page.)
2. In the same example cited above, when I'm at the `Level1` page, I want the **"Home"** link's text change to **"Category 1"**; and when I'm at the `Category1` page, I want the link to change back to **"Home"**. `In short, the link's text would be the name of the previous page.` But when I'm at the homepage, I want it to change to **"Welcome!"**
3. I want this all to be dynamic.

This is the initial Navbar.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">
        <p className="home-link">Home</p>
      </Link>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant get parent of current route by this example and set it on inner text of home BTN.

```
window.location.pathname.split('/')[window.location.pathname.split('/').length - 2]
```

every where you want to back to last step this line of code can help you show previous step name and router of previous step too depends on whats your current URL so you can push into history to change route or show to users